# How to get the special gadget ID?

Tags: android

I want to know how to get android id (unique id) i am using

```
  private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure._ID);
```

but didn't find any id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this  `Secure.ANDROID_ID` instead of `Settings.Secure._ID`

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```